# Xamarin using Async and Wait

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, async-await

I want to perform two things parallelly - I have a Timer which shows time on Main thread (UI level) and web service calls in background.

To perform this i am looking at C# Async and Wait. Even using Async when i call a web service my time label freezes which i am updating on main thread.

Here is my timer code to update UI view label on Main thread

```
    void UpdateTimerLabel (string timeVal)
    {

        MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.InvokeOnMainThread (delegate { 

            timerLbl.Text = timeVal;
        });
   }
```

Timer freezes till the thread for web service call is live and then it catches up. 
Is there a way i can update timeLbl on main thread and call web service on other thread so it won't get in between my timer..

Comment: What do you use to call the web service? I.e., a generated proxy, `HttpClient`, etc?

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest to call web service? Is there a advantage using HttpClient

Comment: `HttpClient` is a portable wrapper over `HttpWebRequest` with well structured `Task`-based API, it's usually recommend to use it instead of `HttpWebRequest`. You shouldn't need other threads explicitly when using it. So, what exactly are you trying to do in parallel? Does the timer task and the web service poll task depend on each other, at all?